# Ruby on Rails Webrick server on HTTPS protocol stopped after few hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, webrick

I am using the below environments:

```
Server: Webrick
Rails: 3.2.6
Ruby: 1.9.3p555
```

I have added the below code in /script/rails :

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
require 'rack'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'

if ENV['SSL'] == "true"
  module Rails
      class Server < ::Rack::Server
          def default_options
              super.merge({
                  :Port => 443,
                  :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production").dup,
                  :daemonize => false,
                  :debugger => false,
                  :pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
                  :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
                  :SSLEnable => true,
                  :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                  :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
                                   File.open("certs/project.key").read),
                  :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
                                   File.open("certs/project.crt").read),
                  :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]],
              })
          end
      end
  end
end

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

I have added the below line in /config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Start rails on 80 and 443 both using two different pid:

```
SSL=true rails s -p 443 -e production   
rails s -p 80 -P SERVER2 -e production
```

Everything is working fine however after 10-12 hours https protocol stop to respond to the browser and even there is nothing add in the log file.

Could you please confirm what is the issue and how could it be corrected?

Comment: You should not be using Webrick for any kind of production usage, as it is single threaded and its performance can be bad. I would recommend investigating using Unicorn + nginx.

Comment: I have setup with passenger and apache. let see if it is happening again.

Comment: That's a good combination also.